# wordpress multiple page content as posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display multiple pages as a category posts pages.

```
<?php
              $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

              foreach( $mypages as $page ) {    
                $content = $page->post_content;
                if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
                  continue;
                $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );

              ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
                <div class="entry">
                  <?php echo $content; ?>
                  <?php echo $page->post_title; ?> 
                  <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
                      <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured');?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
              <?php
              } 
            ?>
```

I have this, but this code is showing me the whole content of each page, I need to show like a post with the "read more" link and small content. Any idea? thanks

Comment: Check on `the_excerpt()` for the small content and `the_permalink()` for the read more link.

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
<?php
     $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

     foreach( $mypages as $page ) {    
           $content = $page->post_content;
           if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
              continue;
           $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );

           ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
            <div class="entry">

              <?php echo $page->post_title; ?> 
              <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>">read more</a>
              <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured');?>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          <?php
          } 
        ?>
```